# linq query to split a time interval into daily batches with part days at start and end

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following dates

```
2/19/2014 12:16:28 PM (Ticks: 635284091223116843)
2/23/2014 9:10:33 AM (Ticks: 635287435672549275)
```

What is the easiest way to obtain a list of intervals split into daily batches so that the first batch starts at 12:16:28 to midnight. Then full day intervals until start of day 2/23/2014 which is then the last part day until the exact end time.

I need to split this period into daily intervals.
The interval needs to work when start and end fall on the same day.

My Naive initial attempt looks like this:

**Algorithm:**

I am sure this can be done with a neat elegant linq query, rather than my cludgy first attempt.

```
var current = start;
while (current.Ticks < end.AddDays(-1).Ticks)
{
    new [] { current, current.EndOfDay() }.Dump("interval");
    current = current.AddDays(1).StartOfDay();
}
if (end > current)
    new[] { current, end }.Dump("interval");
```

**Result:**

```
2/19/2014 12:28:19 PM 
2/19/2014 11:59:59 PM 

2/20/2014 12:00:00 AM 
2/20/2014 11:59:59 PM 

2/21/2014 12:00:00 AM 
2/21/2014 11:59:59 PM 

2/22/2014 12:00:00 AM 
2/22/2014 11:59:59 PM 

2/23/2014 12:00:00 AM 
2/23/2014 09:22:24 AM
```

**Extension Methods:**

```
public static DateTime StartOfDay(this DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
public static DateTime EndOfDay(this DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve. Can you give example input and desired output?

Comment: Why do you insist on LINQ? I'd reformulate it into a `for` loop.

Comment: the output I have produced is correct. I just don't think it's a very elegant solution. There is a single interval produced per day including the part days on the first day and last day. The linq solutions in the answers all produce different output to what I have. Perhaps my loop is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    {
        var dStart = new DateTime(2015,2,12,1,15,0);            
        var dEnd = new DateTime(2015,2,12,1,15,0);
        var x = Enumerable.Range(0, (dEnd.Date-dStart.Date).Days + 1)
                          .Select(c=>Tuple.Create(
                                     Max(dStart.Date.AddDays(c),dStart), 
                                     Min(dStart.Date.AddDays(c+1).AddMilliseconds(-1), dEnd)
                                 ));

    }

    private static DateTime Min(DateTime a, DateTime b)
    {
        if (a>b)
            return b;
        return a;
    }

    private static DateTime Max(DateTime a, DateTime b)
    {
        if (a<b)
            return b;
        return a;
    }
```

with input

```
var dStart = new DateTime(2015,2,19,11,15,0);           
var dEnd = new DateTime(2015,2,23,9,15,0);
```

the output of `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, x)` is

```
(2/19/2015 11:15:00 AM, 2/19/2015 11:59:59 PM)
(2/20/2015 12:00:00 AM, 2/20/2015 11:59:59 PM)
(2/21/2015 12:00:00 AM, 2/21/2015 11:59:59 PM)
(2/22/2015 12:00:00 AM, 2/22/2015 11:59:59 PM)
(2/23/2015 12:00:00 AM, 2/23/2015 9:15:00 AM)
```

Answer (score 1):

think this is what you're after (or a close approximation of it):

```
private void DoBatch(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        TimeSpan between = to - from;

        var dateRanges = Enumerable.Range(0, between.Days)
                            .Select(d =>
                            {
                                var dt = from.AddDays(d);
                                return new
                                {
                                    day = d,
                                    date = dt,
                                    startDate = dt.StartOfDay(),
                                    endOfDate = dt.EndOfDay()
                                };
                            })
                            .Select(x => {
                                return new
                                {
                                    startDate = x.startDate < from ? from : x.startDate,
                                    endDate = x.endOfDate > to ? to : x.endOfDate
                                };
                            })
                            .ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ can come very handy in several situations, but sometimes it's not super elegant. I think what you already have is good. If you want a clean and elegant solution you could think of a for loop with a little change. Since I saw you using the function Dump() I assume you use LINQPad :-)

The snippet below is a linq file so you can try in linqpad directly:

```
void Main()
{
    var allDates = new List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>>();
    var startDate = DateTime.Now;
    var endDate = startDate.AddDays(20);

    for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
        allDates.Add(Tuple.Create(date.StartOfDay(startDate),date.EndOfDay()));

    allDates.Dump();


} 
static class DateExt
{

   // Define other methods and classes here
   public static DateTime StartOfDay(this DateTime date, DateTime referenceDate)
   {
       return date.Subtract(referenceDate).Ticks == 0
           ? referenceDate
           : new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
   }

   public static DateTime EndOfDay(this DateTime date)
   {
       return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
   }
}
```

this is the output:

[image: Output]

it doesn't use a LINQ statement but I believe it's clean and short and it requires only a small change to your function StartOfDay().

Hope it helps